# DLOOKUP OVERFLOW 6

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I'm using two unbound `textboxes` as input and 3rd `textbox` as output.
My table contains recods for around 19K which `Dlookup` applies into. but I'm getting overflow 6 error if input contains value from record over around 5K. Any Help? Here are the codes...

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
On Error GoTo Message
Dim r As Integer, s As String
Dim u As String
r = Text0.Value
s = Text2.Value
u = DLookup("ActionBy", "RAW", "[requestid]=" & r & " AND [Type]='" & s & "'")
Me.Text7 = u
Exit Sub
Message:
MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number
MsgBox "Make sure you've entered the correct Values", , "Static Error"
End Sub
```

Comment: Not really found the particular record. I randomly tried some records. Can you tell me why this happens? So that I could dig into.

Comment: Ok, I'm off work now. I'll test that in the AM and confirm you back...

Comment: I think integer r is too small for some values. Change it to `Long`. You'd better comment line `On Error GoTo Message` and run again, it will stop on error line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can fail for many reasons. Try this more robust version:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

    ' Uncomment this line when code is verified:
    ' On Error GoTo Message

    Dim r As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim u As Variant

    r = Nz(Text0.Value, 0)
    s = Nz(Text2.Value)
    u = DLookup("ActionBy", "RAW", "[requestid]=" & r & " AND [Type]='" & s & "'")
    Me.Text7.Value = u
    Exit Sub

Message:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number
    MsgBox "Make sure you've entered the correct values.", , "Static Error"

End Sub
```

Also, rename `Command4` to something meaningful.